# How do I configure ASP.NET 5 MVC to use aspx views?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a large web-application with a lot of `.aspx/.ascx/.master` view files that I would like to upgrade to ASP.NET 5, however the ability to load WebForms files is not supported by default in v5. I can't see how I can load/enable the WebForms view-engine.

Note that I'm not asking about WebForms in general. I'm only interested in WebForms-as-a-View-Engine within an MVC context.

Comment: Do your aspx views contain server controls? If not, why not just make the syntax changes to turn them into Razor files? And if they do contain server controls, you're going to have to rewrite them anyways.

Comment: @mason None of them contain any server-controls, but I do subclass the `Page` class and use that in my `Inherits=""` expressions (for example, for strongly-typed `ViewData` that is separate from `Model`), and there is a *lot* of view files that converting them to Razor would take a lot of time.

Comment: Sounds like you built up some technical debt, and should just bite the bullet and use Razor.

Comment: You could automate most of the process of making the conversion - see [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2bfd1ca-9808-417c-b963-eb1ea4896790) and [this](https://razorconverter.codeplex.com/). And [here is a guide](http://beletsky.net/2011/07/switching-from-aspx-to-razor-view.html) to help you make any manual conversions.

Answer (score 2):

I have searched through the [ASP.NET 5 source repositories](https://github.com/aspnet) and cannot seem to locate any support for WebForms. There is only [1 implementation of `IViewEngine`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/95b3d2c1ddc7491ccc9bf297f7a8688cde5d8ae2/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor/IRazorViewEngine.cs) and it is Razor (well, there is a composite one, too so you can plug in multiple view engines). But, as ASP.NET 5 is still a pre-release that doesn't necessarily mean that adding a WebForms view engine is not part of the plan.

That said, according to the [ASP.NET 5 Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) at this stage the first release is feature complete. This means the initial release in Q1 2016 will surely not have support for WebForms.

I would suggest [opening an issue on the MVC repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues) to see what the official plan for WebForms (if any) is.